# How to return duplicates and non duplicates in 2d list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d list with the same values in some of the rows.
I would like to return only duplicates and non-duplicates from the duplicates in the rows.
For example, here is my list

```
df = [[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6,7],   # dup 2, 6
      [5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 34, 48], 
      [3, 5, 6, 7, 45, 46, 48],
      [6, 7, 14, 29, 32, 6, 29], # dup 6,29
      [6, 7, 13, 23, 33, 35, 7], # dup 7
      [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8],    # dup 8
      [0, 2, 5, 7, 19, 7, 5]]    # dup 5,7

dup = [[2,6], [6,29], [7], [8], [5,7]]

non_dups = [[1,4,5,7], [7,14,32], [6,13,23,33,35], [1,6,7,9,10], [0,2,19]]
```

Comment: Surely the first sub-list in non_dups should be [1,4,5,7]. If not, why not?  Also, what would the output look like if one of the sub-lists contained only duplicated values - e.g., [1, 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description and ignoring the seemingly flawed output you could do this:

```
from collections import Counter

df = [
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7],
    [5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 34, 48],
    [3, 5, 6, 7, 45, 46, 48],
    [6, 7, 14, 29, 32, 6, 29],
    [6, 7, 13, 23, 33, 35, 7],
    [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8],
    [0, 2, 5, 7, 19, 7, 5],
]

dups = list()
non_dups = list()

for e in df:
    _dups = list()
    _non_dups = list()
    s = set()

    for i, c in Counter(e).items():
        if c > 1:
            if not i in s:
                _dups.append(i)
                s.add(i)
        else:
            _non_dups.append(i)

    if _dups and _non_dups:
        dups.append(_dups)
        non_dups.append(_non_dups)

print(f"{dups=}")
print(f"{non_dups=}")
```

**Output:**

```
dups=[[2, 6], [6, 29], [7], [8], [5, 7]]
non_dups=[[1, 4, 5, 7], [7, 14, 32], [6, 13, 23, 33, 35], [1, 6, 7, 9, 10], [0, 2, 19]]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hi, I have a simple solution for your question**

```
df = [
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7],
    [5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 34, 48],
    [3, 5, 6, 7, 45, 46, 48],
    [6, 7, 14, 29, 32, 6, 29],
    [6, 7, 13, 23, 33, 35, 7],
    [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8],
    [0, 2, 5, 7, 19, 7, 5],
]

dup = []
no_dup = []

for sublist in df:
     one_count = [item for item in sublist if sublist.count(item) == 1]
     more_count = list(set([item for item in sublist if sublist.count(item) >= 2]))
     if len(more_count) != 0:
          dup.append(more_count)
     if len(set(one_count)) != len(sublist):
          no_dup.append(one_count)
```

**Output**

```
no_dup = [[1, 4, 5, 7], [7, 14, 32], [6, 13, 23, 33, 35], [1, 6, 7, 9, 10], [0, 2, 19]]
dup = [[2, 6], [29, 6], [7], [8], [5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's one way you can do it.**

### **code:**

```py
df = [[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6,7],
[5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 34, 48], 
[3, 5, 6, 7, 45, 46, 48],
[6, 7, 14, 29, 32, 6, 29],  
[6, 7, 13, 23, 33, 35, 7],  
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8],     
[0, 2, 5, 7, 19, 7, 5]]
dups=[]
non_dups=[]

#traverssing through the list of lists
for list in df:
    #if no duplicates then skip the row/list
    if len(set(list))==len(list):
        continue
    #temp_lists to add duplicates/non-duplicates as a list
    temp_dups=[]
    temp_non_dups=[]
    #traverssing through a row/a "inner list"
    for element in list:
        #if element not already in temp and it's count is >1
        if (element not in temp_dups) and (list.count(element)>1):
            temp_dups.append(element)
        #if element is not a duplicate and not already on the temp_non_dups
        elif (element not in temp_non_dups) and (element not in temp_dups):
            temp_non_dups.append(element)
    #appending temp lists to actual lists
    dups.append(temp_dups)
    non_dups.append(temp_non_dups)
            
print(dups,'\n\n\n',non_dups)
```

### **output:**

```
[[2, 6], [6, 29], [7], [8], [5, 7]] 


[[1, 4, 5, 7], [7, 14, 32], [6, 13, 23, 33, 35], [1, 6, 7, 9, 10], [0, 2, 19]]
```